# How to append the last row of a matrix to an empty matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

Suppose I generate a matrix with random numbers which contains 500 rows and 3 columns. If the last row of the first matrix is different for each loop. How can I append the last row of this matrix to append on the empty matrix for 1000 times?

Suppose the first matrix called mat1 and the second matrix called mat2.

I tried the following code:

`for (i in 1:1000) { mat2 <- rbind(mat2,as.vector(mat1[500,])) }`

But it keeps pop up number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, the last row of mat1 can be obtained. But don't know why it cannot be append on the empty matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop iteration seems to be only on the last row or 1000

```
for(i in 1:1000)
```

instead of

```
for(i in 1000)
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
mat2 <- mat1[0,]
for(i in 1:5) {mat2 <- rbind(mat2, mat1[nrow(mat1),])}
mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    6    9
#[2,]    3    6    9
#[3,]    3    6    9
#[4,]    3    6    9
#[5,]    3    6    9
```

---

Or using `replicate`

```
t( replicate(1000, mat1[nrow(mat1),]))
```

or use `rep`

```
mat1[rep(nrow(mat1), 1000),]
```

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. I will correct it in the box. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephLee It works with my reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you.  But if you have 500 x 3 matrix `m` and you want the last row then:

```
nrows <- nrow(m)
lrow <- m[nrows, ]
```

If you want fill an empty matrix `m2` with 1000 copies of lrow then simply:

```
m2 <- matrix(lrow, nrow = 1000, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Note that R replicates data if it can to meet the declared dimensioning.